# Python Labelling in ArcGIS - Two Languages one string

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python-parser, string, maplex

I am trying to format a label in two languages in a way they appear on one line and not stacked in ArcGIS any ideas? Maplex Stacked label feature is not ticked so this does not help.
This is how they currently appear when labelled with the following python code:

> River Corrib
>  Abhainn Na Gaillimhe

```
def FindLabel ([ENG_NAMED_RIVER], [GLE_NAMED_RIVER], [GAELTACHT_AREA]):
    try:
        s =[ENG_NAMED_RIVER]
        s = s.title().upper()

        if ([GAELTACHT_AREA]) == "Y":
            return "<ita>"  +  ([GLE_NAMED_RIVER]) + "</ita>"
        elif ([GAELTACHT_AREA]) == "N":
            if [GLE_NAMED_RIVER] is None and [ENG_NAMED_RIVER] is not None:
                return (s)
            else:   
                return (s) + '\n' + " " + "<ita>"  +  ([GLE_NAMED_RIVER]) + "</ita>"
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

But I just want the label to read like:

> River Corrib Abhainn Na Gaillimhe

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user, please take a few minutes to [take the Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). I also recommend checking out the [formatting options for posts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)  to ensure that your code comes through clearly on any future questions.

Answer (score 2):

The `\n` is a newline character, so it automatically creates a second line at that point. Remove it from the line `return ( s ) + '\n' + " " + "<ita>"  +  ( [GLE_NAMED_RIVER]) + "</ita>"`.

Comment: Quick reminder: If this works as a solution for you, please remember to come back and mark it as a helpful (vote up) and/or accepted answer (checkbox).